# How to correctly marshal unmanaged UTF-8 string to .NET runtime?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C function that returns an UTF-8 string. Before it returns, it does a strdup(), and returns that. Thus, it is up to the caller to free() it.

I want to call this method from the .NET runtime.

I found the following custom ICustomMarshaler online:

```
class Utf8StringMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    static Utf8StringMarshaler _singleton;

    static Utf8StringMarshaler()
    {
        _singleton = new Utf8StringMarshaler();
    }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
    {
        if (managedObj == null)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        if (!(managedObj is string))
            throw new MarshalDirectiveException("Utf8StringMarshaler must be used on a string.");

        var stringBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)managedObj);
        var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(stringBuffer.Length + 1);

        Marshal.Copy(stringBuffer, 0, buffer, stringBuffer.Length);
        Marshal.WriteByte(buffer + stringBuffer.Length, 0);

        return buffer;
    }

    public unsafe object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        byte* walk = (byte*)pNativeData;

        // Find the end of the string

        while (*walk != 0)
            walk++;

        var length = (int)(walk - (byte*)pNativeData);

        var stringBuffer = new byte[length];

        // Skip the trailing NULL

        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)pNativeData, stringBuffer, 0, length);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringBuffer);
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNativeData);
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object managedObj)
    {
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return -1;
    }

    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie) => _singleton;
}
```

And am using it as such:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("libfoo", EntryPoint = "my_function")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(Utf8StringMarshaler))]
public static extern string my_function(System.IntPtr param0, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(Utf8StringMarshaler))] string data);
```

Now, I am uncertain if .NET now free()'s the original UTF-8 string. Am I doing it correctly, or do I have a memory leak? What do I need to do to not leak?

Comment: Have you tries using `byte[]` as the parameter type? That's what it's pointing to. Then `Encoding.UTF8.GetString([bytes])`. Managed code has a Garbage collector guy.

Comment: A string in c# is a class that contains characters that can either be one or two bytes with a private property that indicates the if each character is one or two bytes.  In c++ a string consists of one bytes characters and terminates with a '\0'.  So to get one byte in c# you need to use a byte[] and then terminate with the '\0'.  Most people use Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR which does the work automatically.

Comment: .NET nows nothing about strdup(). nor free() or the fact the pointer it has must be freed. The easiest way is to export a "free" function that you could use in your MarshalNativeToManaged method. Implementation would call C's free().

Comment: @jdweng No. PtrToStringBSTR allocates a COM BSTR which is UTF16 encoded string with a length field stored in meta data.